# KafkaListner is not resolving topic name

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on [apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) + spring and java api. Facing really annoying issue. I have used kafka topic pattern approach to listen event for multiple client. 
Following is the code of kafka consumer in which topic name is coming from config file and suffix has hard code value.

`${${service}.topic} value - test-env.demo.*.v1`
suffix value is - .cqrs.customer

```
@KafkaListener(
            topicPattern = "${${service}.topic}" + Constants.suffix,
            groupId = "test",
            id = "test")
```

So final topic name that will be resolved for customer abc.

```
test-env.demo.abc.v1.cqrs.customer
```

and for customer xyz will be

```
test-env.demo.xyz.v1.cqrs.customer
```

but when producer emits event on any of following topic. Consumer did not listen anything.

Could someone help me on this.

Thanks

Comment: i would check in the logs if the client is connected and where and what is at runtime the actual value of `topicPattern = "${${service}.topic}" + Constants.suffix,`

Comment: Are you sure spring allows you to have nested values like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can grep the phrase "partitions assigned" in the application log, this line will contain information about which partitions are assigned to your application. If successful, should be something like:

```
partitions assigned: [test-env.demo.abc.v1.cqrs.customer-0],
```

If the partitions assigned is empty

```
partitions assigned: []
```

there may already be some other consumer instances in the "test" group and messages are being processed by them. In this case, try changing the name of the group.